# Is a "repeat password" field necessary in a signup page?

Tags: password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should we ask the password twice during registration?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20953/why-should-we-ask-the-password-twice-during-registration)

When designing a new and simplified signup page I got into an argument with a colleague about the necessity of the "repeat password" field.

We designed the signup process in such a way that the user will be logged in automatically after completing the email verification process. So, at least initially there will be no need for the user to enter their password. Therefore the user will only 'verify' the password when logging in the second time in case we omit the "repeat password" field.

We do have a "recover password" option so in the worst case the user could go through that process in case they mis-typed the password when signing up. But then again, how often do you mis-type your password?

Even the big players don't seem to agree on which way is the best...

Don't need to re-type the password:

- Twitter
- Facebook (although they require re-typing your email)
- Dropbox

Need to re-type the password:

- Yahoo
- Reddit

Is this necessary?

Comment: The point of having to repeat your password is to demonstrate how easy it is to miss-type the same thing twice in succession.

Comment: DropBox doesn't have a repeat box, and the signup feels really confortable.

Comment: Passwords are evil! Seriously, this repeat password rubbish is slowly dying out in the sites that have better signup and signin interaction designs.
Try creating a new account on http://www.librarything.com/ for instance.

Comment: openid is nice for home users, but if your site is aimed at larger corporates then a lot will have openid providers like yahoo blocked, possibly even myopenid.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I'm surprised no-one has mentioned the Lotus Notes approach ;) ![See this link to a Lotus Notes password dialog animation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cLUZM.gif) By pure coincidence snapped from [a Coding Horror post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/02/the-dramatic-password-reveal.html) on the subject with a lot of comments.

Comment: Twitter did great by me- their "don't need to retype your password" also includes a "don't tell you that you can't include spaces in your password" feature that caused me to create a password when I signed up that could not be accepted by their password page but they didn't tell me that at the time. Only after going through arduous password recovery did I find a page that finally told me my previous password was unacceptable...

Comment: Typing a password incorrectly is incredibly rare, IF you're **reusing** the same password across multiple sites, because you've already typed it a thousand times or more. Users who follow better practice, by having a unique password for each site, are much more likely to mistype as they don't have the muscle memory trained.

Comment: Another thought: If you don't ask for a confirmation of their password at the time of signup, then you should provide more assistance if they have problems signing in for the first time with that password.

Comment: All of you are gracefully missing the point! **The re-type your password field is for the peace of mind of your users**; not yours. People are insecure when typing their passwords in a registration form (even when it's one they've used before). Yes, they can go though the (troublesome) re-cover your password field (even if it's right after registration), however if you have any common sense you'll know many of your users don't want that; and will go though a test of patience before realizing the problem, -if- they realize the problem at all. Rule #1: your users are not as "smart" as you.

Comment: [Jacob Nilsen - Stop Password Masking](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/passwords.html)

Comment: We've closed this as a dupe as we've got a newer, more focused question. This Q/answers got sorta derailed and I'd rather not bury any new answers in here.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I'm no UI expert but I think in many cases it is unnecessary.  Certainly in my own experience it is rare for me to enter a password incorrectly.  A better solution is to not have a password at all.  Use one of the growing number of authentication providers (e.g., OpenId, Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc).  Why does the user need another password for your app or site?

The technical users of your app will use a password generator and/or storage mechanism.  The non-technical users will use one of the favourite throwaway passwords that they use for many different sites/apps.  Better to just integrate with an authentication system they already use.  There may also be other knock on benefits for your application such as integration into Google Apps if you use Google's auth.

If you do choose to require the user to provide a new password to your application then at least don't clear the password field on form entry error.  Nothing is more infuriating than having a password field get cleared because you make an error in some other part of the form.  You fix the error resubmit and then there is an error again because the password is missing.  This drives me nuts.  If you are concerned about echoing the user's password back in the HTML, don't.  There are many other options.  Encrypt it in the form, remember it in session state, use a dumby password in the HTML.  Whatever, just don't force the user to enter it again!

Comment: +1 using OpenID or similar and for not clearing the password on error.

Comment: +1 I like the idea of deferring authentication to a trusted third party.

Comment: See: http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/78/whats-more-user-friendly-local-authentication-or-remote-authentication-openid-o

Comment: Just OpenID!! Do something like stackoverflow. provide buttons for simple login using OpenIDs.

Comment: +1 especially for the order of providers: OpenID, Google, Facebook, Twitter seems the right order to support providers. I'd rather have my app work only with facebook than only with twitter.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. Users still have to sign up with OpenID/Facebook/Twitter etc in order to sign into other sites/apps. You can't assume that they have those accounts or would want to use those accounts to sign in.

Comment: I would also add third party apps as authentication providers. But please consider: Nobody (statistically speaking) has an OpenID and knows of it. Our webservice has several hundreds of thousands of users and less than 5% of all logins are openID logins.

Comment: @pipTheGeek I always enjoy my password not being deleted after a failed try, but I complicate things a bit in my applications. I use JavaScript to hash the password on the spot, which in turn I send to PHP with Fetch API. On error the UI shows an error message, but does not delete the password. On success it replaces password in UI with hash (dots), so the user might understand what I did. Feel like it's safer that way. And there is always a Login with Google/Facebook option as well.

Answer (score 28):

Microsoft has a pretty nifty way to solve this: the unmask password checkbox (connect to WiFi in Windows 7, and Vista I think). I really think that's the best of both worlds.

I personally don't have people looking over my shoulder 24/7; and neither do most users. Furthermore you can type the password in and simply unmask/mask to briefly check it.

Comment: A List Apart has a nice article about this, see [The Problem with Passwords](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/the-problem-with-passwords/). Suggesting to have a checkbox to hide the text or to show the last types key as a normal letter.

Answer (score 26):

It's not a requirement, especially if you have a way to reset it. I would bet that a lot of people use cut and paste on that anyway. I tend to be of the mindset that signing up for anything should be as easy as possible. JMHO.

Comment: +1 agree, as long as I can change it easily, I don't care.

Comment: I think the idea is that if you type the password twice it's supposed to help you remember it - not sure whether that actually works though.

Comment: @Chris I thought it was to make sure you didn't make a typo.

Comment: @ChrisF I was always under the impression it was just to prevent typos.  Never thought about the memory assistance part.

Comment: Point taken on the typo prevention.

Comment: I've been saved a couple times on the typos. I'm sure the reason it's there is the first internet company that required a password did not have two fields, but only had one field. 80 percent of their support calls where how to change a password. So they added a second field and created an automated way to retrieve and change the password.

Comment: +1 Agree.  I don't even like hiding the characters.  Joining a WiFi network on windows allows me to check a box called "show characters".  I use that every time.

Comment: You cannot cut to the clipboard from a password field in the browsers I've used.

Comment: @Glen - it's amazing how many people feel insecure when typing a password in plain text.

Comment: @ChrisF - you know that using a password field is plain text too, right? It doesn't encrypt the password or anything like that. Yes, I know what you mean, but correct terminology is important too.

Comment: @Charles - yes I know passwords are passed as plain text. I meant unobscured.

Answer (score 23):

The question boils down to "what's the cost of a mistyped password". With some systems that cost is high, and that's why they ask you to retype. For example if you are setting up an account on a (non-free) ISP then being unable to access your account probably involves going through a whole load of identify verification steps with tech support.

With a lot of free online systems the cost of a password mistype is low. If you mistyped your Twitter password the worst that can happen is that you have to create an account a second time. Likewise if you mistype it in Facebook, and they've got your email, you can request a password reset, which is why they ask for your email twice and not your password.

As most systems become the second type, rather than the first, password repeats are going to get rarer.

Comment: I agree with the argument ‘cost of a mistake’. It's better to _prevent_ mistakes from happening than to offer ways to fix them. In an encryption desktop app, the cost of a typo would be very high (bye bye data), so having to enter it twice is a small fee to pay.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, sometimes. Why? Because sometimes you don't verify a user's details when they sign up, meaning that if they forget their password, it's more difficult to allow them access again.

**Reddit** and **Yahoo** don't verify email addresses (at all), so it's more important that the user doesn't forget their password. This is why they have two password boxes.

**Twitter** and **Facebook** don't give users full access if they haven't verified their email address. Since they want their users to be verified, ideally, it's more important to get their contact details correct than their password.

I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 9):

have you ever create a password protected archive file.

[image]

[image]

while creating a password protected archive file using winrar, there is one option "show password". If you check that option, you no need to retype password.
Because when password is not visible its a high probability that user can make a mistake.
and he will end up with a wrong password.

most of the users are not software engineers.

Answer (score 4):

I've been moving away from masked password fields.  If the user sees what they're writing, they're better able to remember it (visual enforcement), they can see if there's typos, there's no need to re-type it, and my personal opinion is that it's less stressful on the user.

Comment: But wouldn't this prevent user from signing up if their computers are not secluded?

Comment: If a user signed up for your site from any of the computers at my place of employment, we would have their password because all of the plain text gets recorded.

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces the same would happen regardless. The only way to prevent it is by using ssl.

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces - how do you record it? By reading the values from the form? By capturing keystrokes? Both of those will read values in password fields as well.

Comment: We have a program that reads every _displayed_ word from every computer it is installed on.  We set up filters so that whenever a word we pick appears on a screen we receive an event.

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces - Exactly how does it do that? I'm sorry, I don't see any way that is possible without doing some screen capture followed by OCR, which is hardly an effective way of doing this sort of thing.

Comment: I like the Symbian (or is it Nokia) approach. When you click a character in a password field, you see it for a second and then it turns into an asterisk. You get to see that you typed the correct character and reduce the chance of someone else seeing it.

Comment: I personally prefer having the password masked and provide a checkbox that allows the user to see the password. Of course this all depends on the applications and the usage scenarios. For example think of an e-mail system like Gmail. There is a possibility that a student is presenting a presentation on a professors laptop and needs to get his/her slides that were e-mailed to himself/herself. This is a case where the individual would want the password field to be masked, because everyone could see the password on the projector otherwise.

Comment: @Waleed -Had not thought of giving the user the option of mask/unmask.  I guess it would have to be selected before typing, and probably wouldn't be possible to show after typing, at least not easily.  Thanks for the idea! I'll be testing this out.

Comment: @Logan / @Charles I too am am confused about the tracking every stroke entered into every field. I've not heard of places doing this, or how it's managed to be stored/retrieved. Would also be interested in the "how" and even more so of the "why?"

Comment: @Susan  In our case, we track our users to prevent inappropriate actions for our environment.  I am not familiar enough with the application itself to know how it is grabbing the information, but it seems to use a combination of techniques because we receive alerts from web content along with contents of files/documents that have been opened on the user's computer.

Comment: @Susan - You can do the masking/unmasking at any time, even after the user has typed something. A password field just stores text, just like a textbox, so you can always read from it when you switch it out (on the web). On a desktop app (Windows, at least) all you need to do is switch the mode of the textbox to show the characters, so it works there too.

Comment: @Susan - here's a blog post I wrote with sample code for doing this on the web: http://www.nexustechnologiesllc.com/blog/fixing-registration-and-login-forms-passwords/ You can see the sample in action here: http://www.nexustechnologiesllc.com/samples/passwordbox/PasswordBoxTest.aspx

Comment: @Charles - Great post, plan on setting up something similar based on your work over the weekend and experimenting. Then trying to put some patterns together.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The point of asking a user to type their password twice is to ensure that there are no accidental spelling errors in their password.  If you skip this step and they did spell something wrong, they would have to go through a whole password recovery/password change process, which can take a while depending on security requirements/user abilities.

I personally feel that just one user having to go through password recovery because of an extra character/missing character/etc is one too many.  Especially when retyping the password is such an easy step.  Of course some people will copy and paste the first into the second, but that is their fault.  I did my best to help the user avoid that issue.

Comment: It's better for the user to give a link to just show the characters while they type.

Comment: You can't copy from a password field. :-)

Comment: I know where you are coming from but I really think I have done this before.  I can't put my finger on it.  Perhaps the form was a standard input field with custom character masking?

Comment: I feel that the one person who made a typo and has to go through the password recovery process should not cause thousands of other users to make an unnecessary step.

Comment: If only it were just one person.  When I was trapped on a helpdesk, the majority of calls were for password related issues.  So maybe the whole system is broken anyway?

Comment: My team deals with garbage data every day because of human error during data input.  It happens, and is it really that much of an extra step to verify?  Sometimes I'm not sure if I did accidentally press that other key, so I erase it all and do it again.  If I didn't go back and there was no verification, I would now be unable to get into the site I just signed up for(assuming no email recovery process).

Answer (score 2):

It's largely subjective and it greatly depends on how your signup process is designed. If the email is confirmed and you have a solid "recover password" process then I would suggest probably not.

If you have *total* control over the UI (ie. not web), you might also consider allowing the user the option to see what they are typing (á la [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/password/ShowPasswordCheckbox/demo.html))

Comment: Why can't you do that on the web? You can do the exact same thing on the web with only a minimal amount of effort. In fact, your demo is on the web, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

So I think as almost always the answer is: It depends.

As others have said:  If you aren't going to be sending the password back to the user or make recovery very easy, than having a double password can be an effective way to avoid user-error (typos specifically).  I have fallen prey to typos on several occasions;  I think with requirements for capital letters the number of typos goes up, but I have nothing but my own anecdotla evidence to prove it.

I don't think you should make this decision based on percieved cost: If I have to create a new account I no longer get my preferred name/username and end up with some weird numeric addition, which itself becomes difficult to remember.  Also the percieved cost to anyone of us will probably be lower than the average user.

I really like the iPhone metod of showing me just the last character I typed.  It does a fairly good job of giving obsfuscation and information in just the right amounts to people who are probably entering in passwords in public places.

I still use the double-password, I'd prefer to err on the side of limiting user error; it's not as bad as the double email.

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought "if your users are not very savvy, a repeat password field helps them avoid errors". But, on the other hand, users that are not computer-savvy might be horribly confused by the second field. After all, in the real world, there is no such thing as repeat fields.

I think the nicest option, but harder to implement, is to not have a repeat, but include a "do not mask my password" box.

Comment: Most people will just fill out the second password field without bothering. If you really want to educate them, make the label clear, add a little explanation or add a “why?” link/popup/...

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project where users didn't have to repeat the password. One day we got an angry email from a user who claimed that we displayed his password - in clear text - in the upper right corner.

It turned out that when he signed up he had entered his password, and then without looking up, tabbed on to the next field and repeated his password. Except that field was 'First name'.

He wasn't stupid, nor was he not paying attention. He was displaying something that we designers should strive for: [Habituation](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taouu/html/ch04s04.html). It's like a turbo switch in the user's head, except you can't always control things at high speed.

There are **at least two broken things** here

1. Having to create an account in the first place (use openid, google, etc)
2. Using passwords for authentication (no real solution yet)

Comment: One problem with this - you say "nor was he not paying attention". Sorry, but you are wrong there - if he typed his password into the first name field, he clearly **was not** paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I've been thinking about two ideas:

1. Start off hiding the passwword. Give the guy a toggle button that will unhide/rehide the password as he's entered it so far.
2. An unhide timeout might work: provide a button that will reveal the password for a half-second or so, then re-obscure it.

In both of these, the user enters the password just once. And he sees a message (not necessarily a prompt, but maybe it should be) to reveal and inspect the password before submit. As a backup, there's always (I think) the guy's email for password reset.

-- pete

Answer (score 0):

**No** it is not necessary.

It depends on how *important* the security of the website is, what impression about security you with to give the user and how strict your password requirements are.

For websites that require passwords to contain certain patterns/numbers/letters, then your best to have the user repeat the password, as my experience has been they are authoring a **new** password. So what they *think* they typed might not be what they entered.

For websites of leisure, is security really that import? Most likely not, and you might be dealing with the ***hit and run*** user sign up. So reducing the effort and time helps to improve your sign up conversion numbers.

For websites offering paid services, then the user has already made/completed the purchase decision. Signing up is just the a process they need to complete to access the service. Double prompting helps build trust that they can access this service they paid for, later. No one wants to reset their password for something they $paid$ for.