# What are the most common mistakes people make when entering their e-mails in a form?

Tags: forms, error-message, errors

I want to write some quite specific error messages for an e-mail form field in order for people to find out what they did wrong more quickly.

– What are the most common mistakes people make when entering their e-mails in a form besides misspelling their own user names? Is it forgetting the @-sign, a dot or domain etc?

Comment: With many mistyped domains you can't really display an error, only a warning.

Comment: @Tony-Bolero Did this question get answered? If so, would you like to mark the answer for AEJBUG…?  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your most common are likely to be:

> - Full stop at end of address
> - Commas instead of full stops
> - Semi-colon or apostrophe instead of @
> - Spaces in middle or at end of address
> - Bracketed note in field – eg. (office)
> - Double periods
>
> Some common misspellings:
>
> - Googlemail – Gogglemail, googlmail, goglemail
> - Hotmail – Hotmial, Hotmal, Hoitmail, Homail, Hotrmail, Hotmil, Hotmaill
> - Ntlworld - Ntlwolrd, ntlword, ntl.world, ntlwrold
> - Tiscali - Tiscale, tiscalli, Tiscally, Tiscaly
> - Btinternet – Btinterent, btinternt
> - Yahoo – Yaho, Uahoo, ayhoo

[Source: Typical Typos in Email Addresses](http://www.2ndimpression.co.uk/tips/typical-typos-in-email-addresses)

Based on the above information, having a list of common email providers which can check after the @ and before the .com would be a nice feature.

Some other typos I could think of (which I do very often) would be typos in .com, so I would normally type .co or .com, so checking these would be useful as well. There is a nice library which I have linked to below which actually does this for you, so take a look.

[Mailcheck javascript library](https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck)

In terms of the first part of the email address there may be some of the users personal information in there for example, aimee@internet.com, I could misspell this as amee@internet.com. Although this might be overkill, still worth thinking about.